# sing next js and linking to the prismic website and I got an error that the page did not load. I want help because the website took me a long time

Tags: next.js

```bash
> npm run dev

> creative-portfolio-a@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink 'C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\.next\app-build-manifest.json'    
    at async Object.readlink (node:internal/fs/promises:963:10)
    at async C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\lib\recursive-delete.js:58:30
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async recursiveDelete (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\lib\recursive-delete.js:51:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)    at async HotReloaderWebpack.start (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader-webpack.js:588:9)
    at async startWatcher (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:1195:5)
    at async setupDevBundler (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:1809:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)    at async initialize (C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\ReactNative\Creative Portfolio\creative-portfolio-a\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:74:30) {
  errno: -4071,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'readlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\abdal\\OneDrive\\سطح المكتب\\ReactNative\\Creative Portfolio\\creative-portfolio-a\\.next\\app-build-manifest.json'
}
```

The site was working, but when I slept and opened the laptop again, it did not work when I pressed npm run dev

Comment: Have you tried to move the project outside Desktop. Like in another partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to connect clerk authentication with my nextjs app, it's throwing the same error here are the steps that can help :

1. npm cache clean --force
2. rm -rf .next
3. rmdir /s /q .next
4. npm install
5. npn dev run
   it should probably work now